# Sending text data according to esp8266 coding

Tags: android, arduino, wifi, esp8266

Can any one help me in How to only send text data to esp8266 node mcu over wifi?

Esp8266 Arduino node mcu code which is getting data that are send from Android app with Okhttp request->

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#define DEBUG true
 
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); // make RX Arduino line is pin 2, make TX Arduino line is pin 3.
                             // This means that you need to connect the TX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 2
                             // and the RX line from the esp to the Arduino's pin 3
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
String voice;



const char* ssid = "VISHAL J";
const char* password = "986713361190";
WiFiServer server(8000); 

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600); // your esp's baud rate might be different
  
   

  //----  1. Settings as Station - Connect to a WiFi network
  Serial.println("Connecting to " + String(ssid));

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);                       // Config module as station only.
  
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //----   2. Settings as Access point - Create a private Wifi Network. Enable the next five lines to use module as Access point
  // Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");                   // Default IP: 192.168.4.1
  // WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);                                     // Config module as Access point only.  Set WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); to config module as Access point and station
  // boolean result = WiFi.softAP("NodeMCU", "12345678");      // SSID: NodeMCU   Password:12345678
  // if(result == true)  Serial.println("Server Ready");
  // else Serial.println("Failed!");

  // ---- Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

  //---- Enter your setup code below
  // connect a switch.  On Virtuino panel add a Led to pin D5





Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  //----   2. Settings as Access point - Create a private Wifi Network. Enable the next five lines to use module as Access point
  // Serial.print("Setting soft-AP ... ");                   // Default IP: 192.168.4.1
  // WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP);                                     // Config module as Access point only.  Set WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA); to config module as Access point and station
  // boolean result = WiFi.softAP("NodeMCU", "12345678");      // SSID: NodeMCU   Password:12345678
  // if(result == true)  Serial.println("Server Ready");
  // else Serial.println("Failed!");

  // ---- Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");

   }



 
void loop()
{
  while(esp8266.available()) // check if the esp is sending a message 
  {
 
    
     delay(10);
    char c= esp8266.read();
    if(c=='#')
    {break; }
    voice += c;
    }
    if (voice.length() > 0) {
  Serial.println(voice);}
   
    }
```

Here is my Android app code to send text data to Arduino node mcu. But it's not working not any operation work. in this code first I get ip, pin and port number and then use Okhttp request to send data in  AsyncTask<> onBackground method.->

```
       private class HttpRequestAsyncTask: AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
        {
            // declare variables needed
            private var ipAddress: String? = null
            private var portNumber: String? = null
            private var parameter: String? = null
            private var parameterValue: String? = null
        constructor(parameterValue : String,ipAddress: String, portNumber: String, parameter: String){

            this.ipAddress = ipAddress
            this.parameterValue = parameterValue
            this.portNumber = portNumber
            this.parameter = parameter
        }

        override fun doInBackground(vararg voids: Void): Void?
        {
            try {
                val httpclient = OkHttpClient() // create an HTTP client
                // define the URL e.g. http://myIpaddress:myport/?pin=13 (to toggle pin 13 for example)
                val request = Request.Builder().url("http://$ipAddress:$portNumber/?$parameter=$parameterValue#").build()
                httpclient.newCall(request).enqueue(object : Callback{
                    override fun onFailure(call: Call?, e: IOException?) {
                        e!!.printStackTrace()
                    }
                    override fun onResponse(call: Call?, response: Response?) {
                        if(!(response!!.isSuccessful)){
                            throw IOException("Unexpected code $response")
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
            catch (e : Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            catch (e: IOException) {
                // IO error
                e.printStackTrace()
            } catch (e: URISyntaxException) {
                // URL syntax error
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return null
        }
   }
```

**Any one can help me to how to send text data over wifi to esp8266 Arduino to node mcu coding of Arduino.**

Answer (score 0):

You have to run a Webserver there in order to get HTTP requests from Android side, so that at the ESP8266 side you can chose the appropriate action. There are libraries for Arduino such as the ESP8266WebServer for example. If you want to reply something to mobile, there is need to run a Client library as well.